# make a div appear next to it on hover of a certain section of the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Lets say i have a narrow image

200px wide and 900px tall

How can I make a div appear next to it on hover of a certain section of the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [map element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) to define areas of your image, you can use different shapes like rect, circle and poly, so basically you can map any complex area.

e.g. in example below I map left and right portion of an image

HTML:

```
<html><body>
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" usemap="gmap"/>

<map name="gmap">
  <area id="left" shape="rect" coords="0,0,135,95"  />
  <area id="right" shape="rect" coords="135,0,275,95"  />
</map>

</body></html>​
```

JavaScript(using jQuery):

```
$('#left').hover(function(){
    alert("left")
})

$('#right').hover(function(){
    alert("right")
})
```

See it in action http://jsfiddle.net/anuraguniyal/GtMXk/3/

​

Comment: how do you findout the coords

Comment: Use a tool such as Dreamweaver.

Comment: @sp-1986 use any simple image app, e.g. paint, gimp most of them show co-ordinates

Answer (score 1):

Put a div on your image, with `position:absolute` and/or `z-index:100`, and bind the `.hover()` event on it.

Answer (score 1):

Get the mouse position, get the image position, calculate the difference to work out which section of the image you're over.

Answer (score 1):

You can position the image with CSS and then use jquery .hover() and .fade() or .show() / .hide()

Comment: .hover() is the Method and the others are examples of effects you can use

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/maphilight

and the demo:

http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html

You might be able to use some code from it.